# Code Completion hides the first line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I do not know whether this happens because I changed my OS to OS X Yosemite. After I changed the OS in the morning, the auto code completion function in my Eclipse also changed the "hint window" to something in the following picture:
[image]

The weird thing is the first line of the suggestions is always hidden, but usually the first line is the line I want to use!

Has anyone met this kind of problem before and is there any good advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems no way to do it. I have tried eclipse kepler and GA version luna, still no luck.